# Python / How to place symbols in a random place on a 6x6 grid

Tags: python, grid-layout

I'm new to Python and programming and I have a problem with one of the tasks for my programming course.

I need to create a game that will be played on a 6 × 6 grid. The grid will represent a map and the game hero will start at position (0,0). Also, upon starting, items will be randomly placed on unique positions on the grid. They're represented as letters/symbols. (e.g. "S", "R", "*")

I have a few problems with this.

1) I'm not sure how to place the hero ("H") on the grid.

2) I don't know how to get the items randomly on the grid.

Could anyone help me with this? This is how I created my grid:

```
board = []

def print_board(board):
    for x in range(6):
        board= (["-"] * 6)
        print(" ".join(board))
    return board

print_board(board)
```

And this is what I tried for placing the hero on the grid:

```
    board[0][0] = "H"
```

However, I'm not sure where I should put this piece of code/if it's even right. Also, I should be able to 'move' the hero (by asking the player whether they want to move left/right/up/down). This probably requires first a function to ask the player for the direction, and then a for loop to execute the movement, right?

This is a beginners course so I think whatever the answer is, it's probably quite simple. I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Sorry for the hassle, I'm very new here as well. Anyway, I tried this:

```
    def PlaceItem(board, item):
        for i in range(len(board)-1):
            board[x] = randint(0,len(board) - 1)
            board[y] = randint(0,len(board) - 1)
            if board[x] == "-" and board[y] == "-":
                board[x][y] = item
                print(board)
            else:
                continue
        return board
```

I have previously defined the items (e.g. sword = "S"). I then called the function as PlaceItem(board,sword). Doesn't work, so I'm assuming there's something wrong.

Comment: You have several issues here: you store the randomly genereated values *in* the board. This is not useful. You need to store them in additional variables x and y. You also do *not* need a for-loop, as a for-loop implies a finite number of placements attempt. You want (in theory) infinite attempts, because you could for 1000000 times try & randomly place the item on the same place. Last but not least you need to use double indices to check your board - board[y][x]

Answer (score 1):

You need to first establish a board that actually respects your requirements:

```
board = [
   [None, None, None, None, None, None], # Row 1 (but accessed with 0!)
   ... 5 more times
]
```

Then you can place your hero as desired. You can also determine a random postion using the `random` module. Look for the `randint`-function.

When placing a character, it's useful to write a function for that which

- gets the board as input parameter. Global variables are evil!
- gets the character as input.
- generates a random position.
- checks if the position is empty!
- if not, back to generating (these last three steps need to go into a loop. Do you know which kind?)
- finally, place the character.

Comment: Please edit your code in your question, it's unreadable in this comment form. It also doesn't make clear where your problem is (I presume you have one).

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking at the library random and specifically :

```
import random
print(random.choice(["S","R","Q"]))
```

Comment: Using the choice function for a continuous range is wasteful. See randint instead.

Comment: Considering the question, this is not the problem here. It might be wasteful  but the author asked to choose randomly among symbols. random.choice is the simplest way.

Comment: Teaching the wrong tools is certainly not "the simplest way". Nor is writing a list of six numbers "simpler" than two. `random.shuffle(list(range(6))[0]` is also a solution. But it's also a bad one.

Comment: There are several approaches to teaching, by your reasoning, the teacher who gave the problem to the author of the question is in the wrong since the game to code exists and nethack is an example of such a game.

Comment: And by your reasoning all code is equal, so better not try to improve?

Comment: Not exactly, by my reasoning, you should improve on my answer and this improvement should depend on context. I think a better formulation to your comment would be : 
"If a ressource is an issue, consider using randint instead which is more efficient for a continuous range".
Again, ressource is probably not an issue here.

Comment: I *did* improve your answer by suggesting a more appropriate function that is less resource intensive and  less characters to type. It was your *choice* to not only ignore this suggestion, but to also get defensive about this. Does this matter in the grand scheme of things? Do we prevent the heat-death of the universe? Probably not. And your updated solution doesn't improve anything, as nowhere in the problem description the selection of the items themselves is described to be randomized. But confusing newbies is certainly something worth in some universe, so good on you!

Comment: I indeed took it as criticism, I didn't ignore it now since I modified my answer accordingly.